# Is the notion of "like"ing content too closely tied of Facebook?

Tags: buttons, terminology, branding

We are implementing a "like" feature on our web product, but we want to avoid being tied or compared to Facebook. While our functionalities differ vastly, we do utilize a "news feed" style of content delivery.

What are alternatives to "like"? We currently implement "high-five", but are revisiting the topic from a UX perspective.

Comment: Need more details on what liking does. Are you liking stuff from your own webpage to use within the website or liking somewhere to use somewhere else?

Comment: Imagine a B2B Activity Stream with a bunch of salespeople. They're either liking other salespeople's posts or customer posts.

Comment: How are these 'likes' used? If I like someone's post, how does that affect my experience and that of other users? What is the motivation behind performing that action?

Comment: YouTube also uses "Like"

Comment: @MattObee the "likes" serve 2 purposes: 1. to publicly display approval (the typical "like"); 2. to indicate to the seller a positive action from the buyer on a piece of content/conversation

Comment: @com.BOY technically Youtube uses thumbs up/down.

Comment: @BenBrocka But the text on the button is "Like"

Comment: This is a great question.

Answer (score 4):

**Up-vote/Down-vote** are quite neutral (in terms of branding and word-association) and give you a good measure of support the post/person has.

Comment: We don't want to allow down-votes in the feed though.

Comment: @Tom  You can use just up-votes too. 'Liking', 'hi-5', etc. are also just the positive halves of the pair ;)

Comment: Is up-vote:reddit, as like:facebook though?

Comment: I wouldn't consider it. There is no 'branding' behind the upvote/downvote in Reddit. Also, if you are considering using just upvotes, it should not be a direct comparison ;)

Answer (score 2):

IMO, yes.

Facebook, for better or worse has pretty much locked that 'word/action' up and any visitor coming is going to correlate 'like' with facebook.

I would suggest "Thumbs Up" (old school) or an "approve". "Approve" is plain and simple and clearly understandable, yet somewhat steril in voice. If it is in relating to a service or product possibly "recommend" So, 24 others have 'recommended' this story/service or product.

Hope that helps you out.

Comment: `Approve` or `endorse` carry with them a significant legal connotation. Not something I'd `recommend` (pun intended).

Answer (score 1):

You can try "**+1**", a neutral way used in google plus and very popular in "forums culture".

Comment: What about Google+? Is +1 too closely (or will it be) associated with that?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this line of thought myself. Off the top of my head, you could try a lot of things. **Heart** and **favorite** are a couple that I haven't seen others in here use, but are still used in popular sites (Tumblr and Twitter).

There are so many of these sites that have similar messages, I think what you need to decide is **what will your users best identify with?** If you put too much pressure on being unique, you may just alienate people. I've seen others go as far as making up words for what is clearly a 'like' functionality and it didn't pan out too well.

If you want to avoid being associated specifically with Facebook (or g+ or whomever), you might consider just using a heart, a star, or a thumbs-up icon.

Answer (score 1):

Liking can be done differently. The Discourse forum allows people to like other people's posts. In your notifications they let you know of the fact with a heart icon next to the text message letting you know. In my experience, although you know that Facebook probably influenced it - it does not feel jarringly Facebook specific. It's a human feeling to want to approve something after all.

[image: Example of it at use on a forum]

View a live forum at: [try.discourse.org](http://try.discourse.org)

Liking things have been around for a while in other forms:

- Dig it
- Heart it
- Luv it
- Kudos/karma points

Simple up votes are fine also. They are not Reddit specific either. [HackerNews](http://news.ycombinator.com/) uses karma up votes, but does not show the number awarded. This is so that people cannot tell if a specific post has more votes than another and then naturally feel more inclined to award their karma points to that higher scoring post.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could go with something like **dig it**, or market the term towards a specific audience. **Kudos** is another popular term.